# Starting with angular 2, what is the best approach?

Tags: angular, laravel-5

I had a question regarding angular 2.

We are using laravel 5.2 as our backend or api provider and want to write our frontend in angular 2. What is the best way to use them together?

1. Serve angular 2 files via laravel on same node.
2. Have separate nodes for front end and backend, where angular 2 runs on 1st node served by node.Js (as most of the examples on angular 2 show) and api services using laravel on 2nd node.

I couldn't find best guide to satisfy the 1st option. Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe both practices are fine.

If you host on the same node, you won't have to specify the API node when making calls. If you see your backend API being a more general service to other applications you are building, consider a second, more general node.

Comment: I tried using 1st, but there were very few guides I found and they were related to beta versions of angular 2. Laravel elexir is what is suggested everywhere but I saw one flaw in that, it asked me to specify all the typescript files (unlike `typings.json`). Also, in 2nd approach I took angular2-seed as base but looking at the config i realise that it runs the server in development mode what would be the config for production?